# Algorithm to create Bayesian priors from measurements

Tags: bayesian, modeling, prior

I am trying to devise a simple algorithm to create a Bayesian prior from measurements obtained from time series data.

Firstly, I presuppose that the data can take on one of five possible "shapes" or "patterns" and then measure the Euclidean distance of each time series data point from its equivalent point in time in each of the five possible patterns, summed over a specified period of time for each pattern. This will give five distinct numbers with the lowest one indicating which pattern the data is most likely to resemble due to the fact that this distance metric is the smallest "error measurement."

However, this is not a sufficient measure in and of itself hence my desire to use it as a prior in a naive Bayesian classifier. My problem is: **how to use these numbers to form a prior?**

I am thinking of using some form of ratio i.e. the numbers are $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ for a total of $15$, therefore: $$15/1=15, 15/2=7.5, 15/3=5, 15/4=3.75, 15/5=3,$$ and so the prior for $1$ would be: $$15/(15+7.5+5+3.75+3),$$ the prior for 2 would be: $$7.5/(15+7.5+5+3.75+3),$$ etc.

Is there any justification for using an approach such as this, or is there perhaps a better approach?